# Jacobian and Newton's method

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

How can we use Newton's method with $x^{(0)} = 0$ to compute $x^2$ for the following system below?

$$10x_1 - 2x_2^2 + x_2 - 2x_3 - 5 = 0$$

$$8x_2^2 + 4x_3^2 - 9 = 0$$

$$8x_2x_3 + 4 = 0$$

I tried to get the Jacobian **matrix** of the system above as:

$$
        \left(\begin{matrix}
        10 & -4x_2 + 1& -2\\
       0  & 16x_2  & 8x_3\\
       0  & 8x_3 &  8x_2\\
        \end{matrix}\right)
$$

but then the inverse Jacobian is the zero matrix and I cannot then get any iteration.

What is the **inverse Jacobian matrix**?

Comment: You should use LaTeX to post mathematics here. There are directions in the FAQ section. I trried to edit your post but wasn't sure of it all...

Comment: Thanks, now its better. Also, I tried to get the Jacobian matrix of the system above, but then when I got the inverse jacobian matrix, it was all zeros. Could you help with that?

Comment: inverse of Jacobian is not zero matrix.

Comment: $det(Jacobian) = 10(128x_2^2 - 64x_3^2)\neq 0$

Comment: @Yimin, OP is starting at the origin.

Comment: @vonbrand I see. thx.

Answer (score 1):

Your starting vector $\mathbf{x} = (0, 0, 0)$ doesn't work, as you discovered. Pick another one. Perhaps try with $(1, 1, 1)$.

Comment: In the book, it says to start with the zero vector, "Use Netwton's method with x^(o) = 0" to compute x^(2). How to do this problem otherwise?

Comment: @BuddyHolly, perhaps the book contains a mistake. Happens to the very best... _don't_ follow insructions blindly if they don't work. If this was homework, I'd show your computation up to this point, show that $(0, 0, 0)$ gives a singular Jacobian, explain why this starting point doesn't work, select another starting point and complete the asignment from there.

Comment: Is this Numerical methods by burden? if so, it does contain a fair bit of errors.

Comment: @TylerHilton, Yes it is.